# Setup Class Path Glassfish Server

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm trying to get a school assignment to run. I've never developed in Java and was given a java web application that I need to run and evaluate and then write test cases. I cannot even get the application to run. I started by installing Glassfish server, per instructions but cannot get any further from here. I've included a screen shot of some of the errors. It seems to be related since those are web libraries. I don't know what libraries I'm missing.
I cannot figure out how to set up a server classpath and did not see anything that seemed to make sense...or I'm searching for the wrong terms to find answer. Can someone please help?

[image]

**Error in output window when trying to build**

The Java EE server classpath is not correctly set up - server home directory is missing.
Either open the project in the IDE and assign the server or setup the server classpath manually.
For example like this:
ant -Dj2ee.server.home=<app_server_installation_directory>
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

**My NetBeans version, including the output of installing Glassfish 7.**

Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 17
Java: 11.0.16; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.16+11-LTS-199
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 11.0.16+11-LTS-199

Running the create-domain subcommand
Using port 4848 for Admin.
Using port 8080 for HTTP Instance.
Using default port 7676 for JMS.
Using default port 3700 for IIOP.
Using default port 8181 for HTTP_SSL.
Using default port 3820 for IIOP_SSL.
Using default port 3920 for IIOP_MUTUALAUTH.
Using default port 8686 for JMX_ADMIN.
Using default port 6666 for OSGI_SHELL.
Using default port 9009 for JAVA_DEBUGGER.
Using default port 4900 for Hazelcast DAS.
Using default port 5900 for Hazelcast Start.
Distinguished Name of the self-signed X.509 Server Certificate is:
[CN=MIkesLaptop.lan,OU=Payara,O=Payara Foundation,L=Great Malvern,ST=Worcestershire,C=UK]
Distinguished Name of the self-signed X.509 Server Certificate is:
[CN=MIkesLaptop.lan-instance,OU=Payara,O=Payara Foundation,L=Great Malvern,ST=Worcestershire,C=UK]
Domain FlyDomain created.
Domain FlyDomain admin port is 4848.
Domain FlyDomain allows admin login as user "admin" with no password.
Command create-domain executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing all those “javax” with “jakarta” in lines that start with “import”. For example:

```
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
```

The latest GlassFish changed the packages to be imported to start with jakarta.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it did not work. The assignment is over and I've moved onto another assignment. I was able to use an IntelliJ to complete the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to pom file or if your not convert your project to maven do it and than add this

```
     <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

or if you don't want to use jump to google and get jar file for maven jakarta.platform add to project build path.
after that you can use jakarta package that replaced with javax!